# Where / How can I check if my minecraft key is an alpha-version?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I bought a minecraft key from another person, which claimed that it was an alpha-version.

How can I check if my key is from the time of the alpha-version?

Comment: Good question. I have no idea. Maybe you could ask Notch?

Comment: I suppose you could use date-of-purchase as an indicator, since accounts purchased pre-beta release are "alpha-version" accounts.

Comment: For @fail badp's idea, you could tweet him. He seems to like twitter.

Comment: @Arkive but where can I see the date-of-purchase, if I didn't bought it myself from Notch directly?

Comment: @Joschua I don't know. That's why I commented instead of answering.

Comment: @Joschua seeems his twitter is here: http://twitter.com/notch

Comment: Side-note: it looks like alpha-keys might get some **expansions for free in future**. This is likely the reason for this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that there is no way to determine the version of your key for yourself ([1](http://www.minecraftforum.net/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=164477), [2](http://www.minecraftforum.net/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=231829)).

You might be able to find out by contacting Mojang directly. Twitter accounts are listed [here](http://mojang.com/about/). You could also try contacting notch@mojang.com or payment@mojang.com.